# How much time it takes for Kundalini activation via padmasana?

Tags: scripture, kundalini, asana, hatha-yoga, padmasana

Hatha Yoga Pradipika says that it takes 12 years to achieve success in Yoga (activating Kundalini) if the Yogi is doing siddhasana

> By contemplating on oneself, by eating sparingly, and by practising
> Siddhâsana for **12 years**, the Yogî obtains success.
>
> [[42, 1: On Âsanas, Hatha Yoga Pradipika]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm)

And it also assures that awakening the kundalini is possible with Padmasana

> Having kept both the hands together in the lap, performing the
> Padmâsana firmly, keeping the chin Fixed to the chest and
> contemplating on Him in the mind, by drawing the apâna-vâyû up
> (performing Mûla Bandha) and pushing down the air after inhaling it,
> joining thus the prâṇa and apâna in the navel, **one gets the highest
> intelligence by awakening the śakti (kundalinî) thus**.
>
> [[50, 1: On Âsanas, Hatha Yoga Pradipika]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm)

But, this scripture may have no verses telling the time for such activation if the aspirant is performing Padmasana.

Do any other scripture mention the time Padmasana takes for the activation of Kundalini?