# Estimation of number of Jivanmukthas in Indian society

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, india, mukti

According to Krishna [in Geetha](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7/verse/3), one can guess that a single Jivan Muktha may exist in atleast 10,00,000 people

> Amongst thousands of persons, hardly one strives for perfection; and
> amongst those who have achieved perfection, hardly one knows me in
> truth.

And there are numerous yoga teachers in society, who have been practicing asanas from atleat twenty years. Verses in scriptures says that if a person practices some asanas for twelve years, [they will get liberation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46761/how-much-time-it-takes-for-kundalini-activation-via-padmasana).

According to these verses, can I safely say that there are atleast 1380 jivan mukthas in India among [total population](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/india-population/)?

But many people claim that there are very less number of Jivan mukthas, order of tens, in society. Am I going wrong anywhere?
Are there any other verses in any scripture that help us in providing stats related to the number of jivan mukthas?

Comment: Why take only Indian population? Krishna can be worshipped from anywhere. Thus, there must be close to 6000 jivanmukthas in the world. Maybe the majority reside in India and they are mostly unknown as they don't like to publicize themselves.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Yeah, I just kept India for example...

Comment: True Jivanmuktas don't live in human society. They don't age or have death or affected by diseases. Do we know of even one such person? @hanugm

Comment: @Rickross- Ramana Maharshi was a Jivanmukta. But it's not true that they don't age or get affected by diseases. They also do so, but they don't identify with the body, thereby they (The Self) don't "suffer".

Comment: No true Jivanmuktas don't age or affected by diseases.@curiousseeker

Comment: @Rickross Did you mention it in any answer that Jivan mukthas don't age or get disease?

Comment: verse says thousands, why u r taking thousand then? hence, these r not exact numbers... estimation is not possible...

Comment: @YDS I took at least 10,000... And also considered yoga masters...